# Call an array outside Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How do I access my array $page_array outside the main foreach loop. Im just unable to print my array content outside the main foreach.

```
$page_array = array(); $j=0;
foreach($temp_ch_output as $ch_finaloutput)
{
   //code
    $pagetitle = $ch_finaloutput['title'];
    if(is_array($pagetitle)){
        foreach ($pagetitle as $pagetitles) {
            $page_array[$j]['page_view'] = $pageViews;
            $j++; 
        }
     } else {
        $page_array[$j]['page_view'] = $pageViews;
        $j++;
     }
}
 print_r($page_array);
```

pagesviews = Google Analytics Value,pagetitle = title of the pages for which im getting the page views and ch_finaloutput = has my array

Comment: can you post full fragment of code? where you initialize $page_array, and where you print it out

Comment: What is `$pagetitle` ? are you sure your `$page_array` has values.

Comment: yes im able to print $page_array inside the foreach loop

Comment: what is the value of $pageviews here?

Comment: Please `echo` something inside main `foreach` loop, maybe it's not cycling? also you can `echo $j`; to see if increment took place

Comment: Anyway your code structure does not really make sense because even you don't know what you do... Unfortunately I've got such impression

Comment: What does `print_r($page_array);` outputs outside foreach? What actually happens? Specify that in the qstn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible that, there is a problem in inside foreach loop the way you are getting the $pageViews;
Other than that I don't think so there is any problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You may declare the variable outside the main foreach loop. Also, indent your code:

```
$page_array = array();

foreach($temp_ch_output as $ch_finaloutput)
{

    if(is_array($pagetitle))
    {
        foreach ($pagetitle as $pagetitles)
        {
            $page_array[$j]['page_view'] = $pageViews;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $page_array[$j]['page_view'] = $pageViews;
    }
}

print_r($page_array);
```

Comment: I have declared it outside the foreach but it dint help

Comment: What do you get when you `print_r` the array?

Answer (score 0):

Just use array variable outside.

```
foreach($temp_ch_output as $ch_finaloutput)
{
         // Your loop
}
print_r($page_array);
```

Comment: even tho the array is declared outside the main for loop,unable to print it

Answer (score 0):

Here you have one issue: `$j` seems undefined here, I think it may be key of main `foreach`?

if `$j` will not be dynamic and will not change every main foreach cycle, `$page_array[$j]` would be overvritten each time it runs.

Also where `$pageViews` comes from?

```
$page_array = array()
foreach($temp_ch_output as $key=>$ch_finaloutput)
{
   //code
    if(is_array($pagetitle)){
        foreach ($pagetitle as $pagetitles) {
            // same issue here, data will be overvritten
            $page_array[$key]['page_view'] = $pageViews;
            // maybe solution $page_array[$key]['page_view'][] = $pageViews;
        }
     } else {
        $page_array[$key]['page_view'] = $pageViews;
     }
}

print_r($page_array);
```

**UPDATE**

OK, you've updated `$j`, but where you use `$pagetitles`? if you loop it?

`$ch_finaloutput`, `$pagetitle`, `$pageViews` nothing connects here to each other looks so messy...

Answer (score 0):

try this, if $pagetitle is not array it should be directly set in `$page_array[$j]['page_view'];`

```
$page_array = array();
foreach($temp_ch_output as $ch_finaloutput)
{
   //code
    if(is_array($pagetitle)){
        foreach ($pagetitle as $pagetitles) {
            $page_array[$j]['page_view'] = $pageViews;
        }
     } else {
        $page_array[$j]['page_view'] = $pagetitle;
     }
}
 print_r($page_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You missing the parameter $j with increment as mention

```
$page_array = array();
$j=0;
foreach($temp_ch_output as $ch_finaloutput)
{
   //code

if(is_array($pagetitle)){
    foreach ($pagetitle as $pagetitles) {
        $page_array[$j]['page_view'] = $pageViews;
        $j++;
    }
 } else {
    $page_array[$j]['page_view'] = $pageViews;
 }
   $j++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code really doesn't make sense in places as follows-

```
$page_array = array(); $j=0;
foreach($temp_ch_output as $ch_finaloutput)
{
   //code
    if(is_array($pagetitle)){
        foreach ($pagetitle as $pagetitles) {
            $page_array[$j]['page_view'] = $pageViews;// Where did u use $pagetitles in this block?
            $j++; 
        }
     } else {
        $page_array[$j]['page_view'] = $pageViews;
        $j++;
     }
}
 print_r($page_array);
```

And where actually you tried to print the array inside the foreach loop?